# Is that Probability function only for discrete case?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Most of the books and sites define *Probability function* for discrete case that is they use the term  as the synonym of *Probability mass function*.

Is that *Probability function* define for only  discrete case?

Is *Probability  density function* not included in  *Probability function*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability mass function (PMF) is used to describe a probability measure which is completely discrete, that is there exist countably many $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $P[\{\omega\}]>0$, and any subset which does not include one of these $\omega$ has probability 0.

A probability density function (PDF) is used to describe a probability measure (on $\mathbb{R}$, typically of the form $P\circ X^{-1}$ for a random variable $X$) which is absolutely continuous. In this case we have $P[A] = \int_A f(x)dx$ and call $f$ the PDF.

Note that these two cases are disjoint, if there is a PMF there cannot be a PDF and if there is a PDF then there cannot be a PMF. To see this, note that if a PMF exists then there is a singleton with strictly positive probability, and if a PDF exists then every singleton has zero probability.

The underlying theme here is that we are trying to describe the probability measure $P$. Since $P$ can be very complicated in general, we make special distinctions for the case of when a PMF or PDF for $P$ exists, as these situations are much easier to deal with.

Comment: in  examination, i was asked to define probability function. There it was not distinct whether i would define PMF or PDF. In such case, what should i define?

Comment: The term "probability function" is ambiguous and should never be used without context. It could refer to a CDF, PDF, PMF, or even the probability measure $P$ itself. Unless you are following a textbook which specifically defines the term, I would avoid it. As far as your examination goes, I would point this out to your instructor.

Comment: My only guess would be that if you are taking a course which is exclusively on discrete probability, then "probability function" most likely means PMF.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained.